# Playing the audio Video files from the internal storage path

Tags: android, media-player

My app Doesn't work in playing video and audio files. I use internal storage for saving the audio video files.here is my code video and audio doesn't play the error showing my code is :Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

```
public class VideoFileActivity extends Activity {
String filePath, fileName;
 MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_dialogue);
    getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("import_pkid", MODE_PRIVATE);
     filePath = pref.getString("file_path", "");
     fileName = pref.getString("file_name", "");

     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null){
            filePath = extras.getString("file_path");
            fileName = extras.getString("file_name");
        } 

        DownloadFiles();
       MusicPlay();

}
public void DownloadFiles() {
    //Downloads Files
}
public void MusicPlay()
    {
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(filePath+"/"+fileName);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use log statement to get value of `filePath` and `fileName`

i use `mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/......./" + name.mp3)` for playing  internally saved audios

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize MediaPlayer.

Add the following before calling methods on 'mp' .

```
 MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
```